# Springboot Join ManytoOne Database relationship with count feature

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to create a function that finds the stats of how many total items were purchased for a given time frame/user. So a result would look like:

```
1) item1, 5
2) item2, 6
3) item4, 82
...
```

I have 3 sql tables that are in charge of recording the transactions:

1. `transactions` <- records the total transaction cost, customer info
2. `individual_items_transaction` <- records each of the items purchased in the transaction and quantity, as well as the individual price of the item, and item ID (Many to one relationship to the `transactions` table)
3. `items` <- holds information about the item name, current price, item description, etc. relational to `individual_items_transaction` table (one to one relationship)

Schema for the tables are outlined as follows:

1. `transactions` table:

   transactionNumber   varchar(12),
   totalPrice  double
2. `individual_items_transaction` table:

transactionNumber   varchar(12),
itemID  bigint,
quantityPurchased   int,
pricePerItem    double,
userID int,
date    datetime,

3. `items` table:

Item_ID bigint,
Local_Item_ID   int,
Item_Name   varchar(50),
Item_Description    text,
Item_Price  double,
Item_Stock  int

I have redacted some info from the table, but you get the idea. I have set up entities and standard repositories for each of the tables. I understand that you can link two tables together with a `@ManyToOne` annotation or `@OneToOne` annotation, but that allows you to only query one entity at a time, or a list of entities at a time, and then you would have to go into each entity to find its associated related entities. How would I structure a query in springboot repositories where I could count the number of items purchased in the last month by a given user, grouped by the item ID/item name? I want a repository call functionally similar to:

```
SELECT
    sum(individual_items_transaction.quantityPurchased) as Quantity_Purchased, items.Item_Name
FROM
    transactions
RIGHT JOIN
    individual_items_transaction
ON
    transactions.transactionNumber = individual_items_transaction.transactionNumber
LEFT JOIN
    items
ON
    individual_items_transaction.itemID = items.Item_ID 
WHERE
    transactions.transactionNumber = individual_items_transaction.transactionNumber AND
    transactions.userID = {insert user id}
GROUP BY
    items.Item_Name;
```

Where the result can be a java object of a list with a given item name and quantity of the item purchased?

Thanks!

BTW an example of my current repository and entity class for the `items` table; all 3 of my tables are structured the same way:

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemsRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemsEntity, Long> {
    ItemsEntity findByItemID(Long Item_ID);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ItemsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Item_ID")
    private Long itemID;

    @Column(name = "Local_Item_ID")
    @NonNull
    private int localItemID;

    @Column(name = "Item_name", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)", length = 50)
    @NonNull
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name = "Item_Description", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String itemDescription;

    @Column(name = "Item_Price", columnDefinition = "double")
    @NonNull
    private Double itemPrice;

    @Column(name = "Item_Stock")
    @NonNull
    private int itemStock;
}
```